# Using Net_Gearman with a codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, gearman, worker

I've built an application using Codeigniter and now I want to use the Gearman job queuing server to background some long-running tasks. I'm using the Net_Gearman PEAR library (less desirable that installing the module, but unfortunately I can't install additional modules on my server setup). Are there any good tutorials or guides out there for a best-practices way of accomplishing integrating this library with codeigniter? Maybe even a custom built library for codeigniter? Thanks!

Comment: Install it via pear, add pear into the include path. Done. No need to configure codeigniter, it's agnostic to codeigniter.

Comment: @hakre, I think this guide might help others http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PEAR_integration what do you think?

Comment: Nowadays I suggest using an autoloader that is compatible with PEAR. PEAR follows the PSR-0 convention, so this should be pretty straight forward. This has the benefit that you can use classes right-away w/o doing anything CI specific (which I think is obviously better).

Comment: @harke, I agree and I would normally either install the Gearman extension or use the PEAR autoloader - however I'm using CloudControl (www.cloudcontrol.com), which is basically PHP-as-a-Service and because of that I don't have the ability to install PEAR. Hopefully this codeigniter solution will work for me I'm about to try it now.

Comment: You can manually install PEAR and/or use the webinstaller. PEAR has one. You can then install the packages you're looking for with a web-frontend, see this document for multiple options: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Gearman library for CI
https://github.com/sunils34/codeigniter-gearman-library